# how to configure storage in lumen 7.0

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

In laravel we can use storage Facade in order to save and read files, but in lumen 7.0 there is no filesystem config available at start.

what I did so far:

1. `composer require league/flysystem`
2. in `composer.json` file, I added the following in autoload section:

```
"files": [
  "app/helpers.php"
],
```

3. then in app directory, I've created `helpers.php` and added the following into it:

```php
if (! function_exists('public_path')) {
    /**
     * Get the path to the public folder.
     *
     * @param  string  $path
     * @return string
     */
    function public_path($path = '')
    {
        return app()->make('path.public').($path ? DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.ltrim($path, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) : $path);
    }
}

if (! function_exists('storage_path')) {
    /**
     * Get the path to the storage folder.
     *
     * @param  string  $path
     * @return string
     */
    function storage_path($path = '')
    {
        return app('path.storage').($path ? DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$path : $path);
    }
}
```

4. I created config directory and I copied the filesystems.php from laravel in it
5. then in order to register the configuration I added the following to `bootstrap/app.php`:

```php
$app->singleton('filesystem', function ($app) {
    return $app->loadComponent('filesystems', 'Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider', 'filesystem');
});
$app->instance('path.config', app()->basePath() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'config');
$app->instance('path.storage', app()->basePath() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'storage');
$app->instance('path.public', app()->basePath() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'public');
```

After doing all changes that I made to lumen, when I try to use Storage Facade for example:

```php
Storage::file($dir);
```

it will throw an error that says:

> Class 'League\Flysystem\Adapter\Local' not found

What is wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 4):

I think you used flysystem version 2.0

I had same issue, and then used v1.1 and it worked.

So run `composer require --dev league/flysystem=^1.1`

source : https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper/issues/1105